# method not found" and "associated item not found" errors in a Substrate pallet function?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-contracts

I am working on a Substrate-based blockchain project and I have the following function in my custom pallet:

```
#[pallet::call_index(8)]
#[pallet::weight(<T as Config>::WeightInfo::create_exchange())]
#[transactional]
pub fn call_smart_contract(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    dest: T::AccountId,
    mut selector: Vec<u8>,
    arg: u32,
    gas_limit: Weight,
) -> DispatchResult {
    let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    ensure!(selector.len() < MAX_LENGTH, Error::<T>::InputTooLarge);
    let value: BalanceOf<T> = Default::default();
    let mut arg_enc: Vec<u8> = arg.encode();
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    data.append(&mut selector);
    data.append(&mut arg_enc);

    pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
        who,
        dest.clone(),
        value,
        gas_limit,
        data,
        pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::deterministic(),
        None,
        false,
    );

    Self::deposit_event(Event::CalledContractFromPallet(dest));
    Ok(())
}
```

I encountered the following errors when compiling my code:

1 - Error: no method named map_err found for struct ContractResult in the current scope

```
--> /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/frame/dex/src/lib.rs:327:5
327 |             .map_err(|e| {
|              ^^^^^^^ method not found in `ContractResult<Result<ExecReturnValue, DispatchError>, <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
```

2 - Error: no associated item named Deterministic found for struct Pallet in the current scope

```
--> /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/frame/dex/src/lib.rs:323:36
323 |                 pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::Deterministic,
|                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `Pallet<T>`
```

3 - Error: arguments to this function are incorrect

```
--> /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/frame/dex/src/lib.rs:317:4
317  |             pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
```

I am not sure how to resolve these errors. Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code and how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what version of the template / pallet-contracts are you using?

```
--> /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/frame/dex/src/lib.rs:323:36
323 |                 pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::Deterministic,
```

It looks like this does not exist, you should probably use something like that instead

```rust
pallet_contracts::Determinism::Deterministic
```

The parameters seems incorrect as well, see [Rust Doc here](https://docs.rs/pallet_contracts/4.0.0-dev/pallet_contracts/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.bare_call)

```
 pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
        who,
        dest.clone(),
        value,
        gas_limit,
        data,
        pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::deterministic(),
        None,
        false,
    );
```

Finally, If you are just trying to deploy contracts, you can probably use this [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) which is already configured with the pallet-contracts (see configuration [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/fe44851126245fec8bf17a39f618d7ce54d0bc76/runtime/src/lib.rs#L333-L368))